# Syncing object change from randomly generated firebase database child

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting real time data updates from my DHT22 sensor installed in the Raspberry Pi onto the firebase database. My goal is to update the web page in real time with the data received. I can't seem to understand how to access the values of the child (with its key being randomly generated)

[image: db structure]

```
      // Get a reference to the database service
  var database = firebase.database();

  // Get element from the DOM
  const tempElement = document.getElementById('temperature');
  const humElement = document.getElementById('humidity');

  // Create temperature database reference
  const tempRef = database.ref('DHT22').child();
// Sync objects changes
   tempRef.limitToLast(1).on('value', function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
          var childData = childSnapshot.val();
          console.log("temperature: " + childData);
          tempElement.innerText = childData;
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the data inside the key try the following:

```
  const tempRef = database.ref('DHT22');
 tempRef.limitToLast(1).on('value', function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
          var childData = childSnapshot.val().Date;
          var timeData  = childSnapshot.val().Time;
          var temp      = childSnapshot.val().Temperature;
          tempElement.innerText = childData;
      });
  });
```

Add a reference at node `DHT22` and then loop using `forEach` inside the random generated key and retrieve the data.